# multiline regex match pattern in brackets ignoring escaped brackets

Tags: regex, flex-lexer

I finally managed to find out how to do this, see https://regex101.com/r/Zls9Kq/5/

```
(?!\\)[{](.|\n)*?(?<!\\)[}]
```

Trying to match

```
sometext {
 blah \{
\}
\{
 \}
}
```

But that expression can't be used in flex.

Anyone know if it can be transformed in a way that will work in flex?

Comment: `(?!\\)[{]` will always pass because a backslash is never a open-brace.

Comment: `But that expression can't be used in flex` why not ? What regex expression can be ? Does it depend upon what regex flex supports ?

Comment: Flex doesn't support negative lookbehind which is why I'm asking if this can be transformed into something else that will work.

Comment: Sure, an equivalent is possible, but what does flex use for regex engine ? Its own home-grown or something reputable ? Otherwise, the equivalent  will have problems, repeats, etc...

Comment: https://www.cs.virginia.edu/~cr4bd/flex-manual/Patterns.html

Comment: What did you find out ? OK, well I'm going to assume the worst regex engine in the world and give you this to try out `([^\\]|^)[{]([^\\}]|\\(.|\n))*[}]` https://regex101.com/r/WBFbWw/1

Comment: It almost works, but it picks up the space before the initial {, but at least flex compiles it and uses it

Comment: Lacking lookbehind assertions, it has to match something before the opening `{`, it can be the beginning of string `^` as well, but it's the only way to insure there is no _escape_ before it. Therefore `([^\\]|^)` Cased solved ? Can we wrap it up with you accepting this as the answer ? Tell me now before it gets marked as a dup

Comment: Yes it works fine.

Comment: Add it to answer rolls .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to assume a limited regex engine and give you this to try out

`([^\\]|^)[{]([^\\}]|\\(.|\n))*[}]`

https://regex101.com/r/WBFbWw/1

**

```
 ( [^\\] | ^ )      # (1), Before the opening {, match not an escape or the beginning of the string
 [{]                # Opening brace
 (                  # (2 start)
      [^\\}]             # Not an escape nor a closing brace
   |  \\                 # Or, an escape anything
      ( . | \n )         # (3)
 )*                 # (2 end), 0 to many times
 [}]                # Closing brace
```

Comment: Don't forget to **_Accept and Upvote_** if this fully (only) answered your question. Take a few days to see if a better answer becomes available.